Axios bad request on my React app with vite (and backend with node)
I've a error on my code, and I can't find what's wrong.
So... On my front-end (React with Vite) I have this code:
import { api } from "./services/api";

const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
const channelId = import.meta.env.VITE_MVORTDX_CHANNEL_ID;

export const fetchPlaylists = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=${channelId}&maxResults=25&key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    return response.data.items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao buscar playlists:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const fetchVideos = async (playlistId) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=${playlistId}&maxResults=25&key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    return response.data.items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao buscar vídeos:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const searchVideos = async (query) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=${channelId}&q=${query}&maxResults=25&key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    return response.data.items;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao buscar vídeos:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};


And on my Back end (node) the .env file is like this:
VITE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY=###
VITE_MVORTDX_CHANNEL_ID=###
PORT=xxxx

The interfaces are connected, but with this error:
(Inspect Console)
youtubeService.jsx:13 Erro ao buscar playlists: 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
fetchPlaylists  @   youtubeService.jsx:13
await in fetchPlaylists (async)     

I've verified many times the API Key and ChannelId :(
